# How to set the background color of a WebView to a hex value?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

How do I set the background color of a `WebView` to a hexadecimal value? I am open to either via `main.xml` or programmatically.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you have defined your `WebView` in an XML resource, you can do the following:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Answer (score 11):

In xml:

```
<WebView
android:background = "#7CFC00"
/>
```

for green etc..

Answer (score 0):

try this from onCreate:

```
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x7CFC00);
```